# Como atualizar outra página que esteja aberta seja em PHP, javascript ou jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa tarde pessoal!

Sou novo na área de programação.

Bom! gostaria de saber como faço para atualizar(refresh) outra que esteja aberta através de uma função seja ela em php, javascript ou jquery.

Exemplo: tenho uma pagina01.php que contém um input e um buttom. Ao clicar, no button, ele atualize a pagina02.php que estará aberta.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi para recarregar uma aba do navegador primeiro você precisa pegar a referencia da janela aberta com a função `window.open();`.

Exemplo, seu JS:

```
    var url = "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=1eefXJ7dFtrF5OUPjKer4Ag&q=random+number&oq=random+num&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i131j0l2j0i203l2j0l5.44842.46396..47369...2.0..0.179.1255.0j11......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..35i39j0i67j0i10.KgraaLNVsIA";
    var childWindow = window.open(url);
```

Para testar:

```
<input type="button" onclick="childWindow.location = url;" value="Reload Popup Window">
```

Não use `childWindow.location.reload();` como mencionado pois os navegadores bloqueiam o acesso `Cross Origin` ao invés disso utilize `childWindow.location = url;` como eu fiz. Você tambem pode chamar a função `childWindow.close();` para fechar a janela.

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente isto não é possível se não foi você que abriu a aba.

A forma de atualizar a página seria através de um `window.location.reload()` no Javascript. Porém, o controle das abas fica completamente nas mãos do browser se o usuário abriu estas abas por conta própria.

Agora, a forma mais simples de manter controle sobre uma das abas é fazendo a abertura através do próprio Javascript dentro da página ao clicar no link:

```js
const janela = window.open('url', '_blank')
janela.location.reload()
```

Veja que agora você tem o controle da aba através da variável `janela`, porém isso não é garantido que irá abrir uma aba, já que o controle completo de abas e janelas é feito pelo browser e cada um implementa o `_blank` de forma diferente.

Ainda sim, tome cuidado porque você só vai conseguir controlar as outras páginas a partir de uma página original, que abriu as demais.

Veja também:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035937/window-open-with-target-blank-in-chrome
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662107/how-can-i-refresh-a-tab-from-another-using-javascript

Comment: É possível atualizar uma aba mesmo que você não tenha aberto ela, contanto que essa aba seja do mesmo domínio. Você pode colocar um event listener no `window` para responder alterações no `localStorage`. Se uma aba modificar o `localStorage`, as outras abas capturam o evento, e podem executar uma função de acordo com o evento recebido.

Comment: Mas ai você está assumindo que ela vai modificar o localStorage. No caso você está criando um evento em algo que não pertence a janela para que, quando o evento acontecer, você tenha um `e` que aponte para a janela que criou o evento para que você possa manipulá-la. Eu, pessoalmente, acho que isso é um pouco de gambiarra...